# The require is not defined in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a Chrome Extension and I want to test *a.js*.

In chrome, *a.js*  depends on *b.js* - which is injected before loading *a.js*.

I am writing some unit tests in Node.JS using *mocha*.  and it requires me to put   *import* or something like `const { functions } = require('b.js')` at the beginning of *a.js*.  But in chrome, `require` is not defined.

I put the below at the beginning of *a.js* but the Chrome extension doesn't work (I can't see errors through)

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined'  && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
   const { functions } = require('b.js'); 
}
```

How to make it work in Chrome and unit tests? for now, I can manually add the *require* before I *npm run test* and remove it when packing the Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve this problem by using `webpack`.

1. run unit tests using `npm run test`
2. deploy using `npm run build` which calls `webpack -p` to packs the ES6 classes into something Chrome extension understands.

You can see this project, which just works perfectly: https://github.com/DoctorLai/VideoDownloadHelper